# What's the correct way to read an array from a csv field in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv, oop

I am trying to save some class objects to a csv file, everything works fine. I can save and read back from the csv file, there is only a 'minor' problem with an attribute that is an `Array` of `Strings`.

[image: Csv file]
When I save it to the file it appears like this: `"[""Dan Brown""]"`

```
 CSV.open('documents.csv', "w") do |csv|
      csv << %w[ISBN Titre Auteurs Type Disponibilité]
      @docs.each { |doc|
        csv << [doc.isbn, doc.titre, doc.auteurs, doc.type, doc.empruntable ? "Disponible" : "Emprunté"]
      }
    end
```

And when I try to extract the data from the file I end up with something like this: `["[\"Dan Brown\"]"]`.
[image: new objects]

```
table = CSV.parse(File.read("documents.csv"), headers: true)
    table.each do |row|
      doc = Document.new(row['Titre'], row['ISBN'], row['Type'])
      doc.auteurs << row['Auteurs'] #This the array where there is a 'problem'
      if row['Disponibilité'] == "Disponible"
        doc.empruntable = true
      else
        doc.empruntable = false
      end
      @docs.push(doc) #this an array where I save my objects
    end
```

I tried many things to solve this but without any luck. I would be thankful if you can help me find a solution.

Comment: My guess is that two of those backslashes (the inner ones)  are not real backslashes but just the representation of double quotes within double quotes. Try verifying the size of the string manually to confirm this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a CSV file, by it's nature, contains in its fields only strings, not arrays or other data types, the CSV class is applying the `to_s` method of the objects to turn them into a string before putting them into the CSV.

When you later read them back, you just get this - the string representation of what once had been your array. The only one who **knows** that 'Auteurs'  should end up as an array of strings, is the application, i.e. you.

Hence on reading the CSV, after having extracted the *autheurs* string, you need to convert it manually back to an Array, because there is no automatic "inverse method" to reverse the `to_s`.

A cheap, but dangerous way to do it, is to use `eval`, which indeed would reconstruct your array. However, you need to be sure that nobody had a chance to fiddle manually with the CSV data, because an `eval` allows sneaking in arbitrary code.

A safer way would be to either write your own conversion function to and from String representation, or use a format such as YAML or JSON for representing the Array as String, instead of using `to_s`.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but as you said I didn't find a way to turn back the `String` representation to an `Array`, I tried what you said with the `eval`, and it seems like it's working thanks. I do get the danger there, but the csv is always generated from my class objects, so I am just fetching the info back.

Comment: @Isumairu : In my project, we have a similar problem, but in our case, the strings are guaranteed **not** to contain a certain character (in our case, a comma), so i simply `join` the pieces of the array on a comma and use `split` to tear them apart. If this does not work for you, what speaks against using JSON? It comes for free with Ruby anyway.

Comment: I mean if I were to change this I'll have to change many other things that are related to it, and I am kind of rushed by time here so I had to find something like typecasting to fix it. Anyways thanks for the invoices.